# How to implement JSON web Token in Angular-Express app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jwt

I have a standard Nodejs + Express + Angular application. After I read several tutorial about JSON Web Token from [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-json-web-tokens-node-js/), [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens) and several more, I tried to implement JWT authentication in my application using this following procedures:

- First, after a successful login event, a token that is received from the server being saved on `localStorage` on client's browser.
- Then, I write a code to intercept all request made by my Angular model to server and add token that I stored before. The interceptor code is derived from **https://gist.github.com/gnomeontherun/5678505**
- Then I write a small javascript code to add my `access_token` to each `<a href="#">`  in my application

  ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a:not([href])").each(function(){
             var href= this.href;
             var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
             if(href.indexOf('?') >= 0){
                 href = href + "&access_token=" + token;
             } else {
                 href= href + "?access_token=" + token;
             }
             $(this).attr('href', href);
        });
   });
  ```

  The problem with this implementation are: it makes my URL ugly and exposes the token to address bar. I'm aware about custom header like `x-access-token` or else, I even use this to get my `access_token`

  ```
  var token = (req.body && req.body.access_token) || (req.query && req.query.access_token) || req.headers['x-access-token'];
  ```

My question is: How to send custom header with `<a>` ? Or is it the "correct" way to implement it ? Or someone have better solution ?

Comment: You could send custom header by using $http service in a ng-click handler.

Comment: my current method is to give access_token parameter to every <a>, including those at navbar. So I think adding ng-click to every single one of them is a little bit laborious. Do you have an example how to do this ?

Comment: If you don't want to add ng-click to every A tag, you could write your directive code in which you can inject click handler automatically to every A tag and use $http service in click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send custom http header by using $http service in a ng-click handler or something.
If it is laborious to add ng-click to every A tag, you could write your directive code in which you can bind click handler automatically to every A tag and use $http service in click handler.

Directive code is something like this.

```
.directive('a', function($http){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function(){
                console.log("You can use $http service.", $http);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

[jsfiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/zp82e3xm/9/)